# Without employing Mean Value Theorem, show that $f$ continuous at $a$ and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ means that $f'(a)=0$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

[Problem 69f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WbNy.png) in Chapter 11 of Spivak's *Calculus* reads **partially** as follows:

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f'(a)=0$ for all $a$ in $(0,1)$. Then [prove something]

The solution manual's first line is:

> For $\varepsilon \gt 0$, the function $g'(a)=f'(a)+\varepsilon=\varepsilon \gt 0$ for all $a$ in $[0,1]$.

Earlier in this problem, Spivak says to **NOT** use the *Mean Value Theorem* (MVT). Given this restriction, I am not sure how one produces the first line of the solution manual. In particular, why does $f'(0)=0$ and why does $f'(1)=0$?

Originally, I would have said $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}f'(x)=0 \rightarrow f'(0)=0$, but this claim (of which the generalization is derived earlier in the book) depends on the MVT, so this must not be how to carry out this proof. Also, earlier in the book we covered Darboux's Theorem...but that, too, required the MVT.

Any thoughts?

We want to show that for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there is a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\forall y \in (0,\delta): \left|\frac{f(y)-f(0)}{y}\right|\lt \varepsilon.$ I feel like some clever $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments can be used in conjunction with $|f(0)-f(x)| \lt \varepsilon_1$ and $\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|\lt\varepsilon_2$

---

*Spivak, Michael*, Calculus. 4th ed, Berkeley, California: Publish or Perish, Inc. (2008). [ZBL1272.26002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1272.26002).

Comment: Isn't it *given* that $f'(a)=0$ for all $a \in (0, 1)$?

Comment: @MartinR yes, but not at $0$ or $1$, which the first line of the solution manual posits.

Comment: How is the function $g$ defined?

Comment: @MartinR $g(x)=f(x)+\varepsilon x$

Comment: I do not have that book. But if $f$ is not differentiable at $a=0$ then $g'(a)$ does not exist either, and the statement makes no sense.

Comment: Chapter 11 of Spivak's *Calculus* only has 67 exercises.

Comment: Usually we speak of continuity in compact subsets and differentiability in open subsets. How would we even analyse differentiability of $f$ at $x=0$, say? What is $f$, even? $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ or $(-\delta, 1]\to \mathbb R$?

Comment: @AlvinL i dont know if this helps, but the context here is $\mathbb R$. As stated in the problem, the application of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=0$ would necessarily imply that $f'(0)=0$...so that's one way. Of course, that statement required using the MVT.

Comment: @AlvinL Doesn't the problem's assumption statement of $\forall x \in (0,1): f'(x)=0$ imply that $f$ is continuously differentiable approaching $0$ from the right side?

Comment: @AlvinL perhaps your point is that there is a distinction between $f'(0)$ versus $f'(0)^+$

Comment: @S.Cramer but does not necessarily imply that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. You would have to assume $f$ is defined on some subset $(-\delta, 1]$ if you even want to hope to speak of differentiability at $x=0$.

Comment: @AlvinL I think we are saying the same thing. I understand what you are saying, at least.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I found the exercise in the 4th edition- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WbNy.png

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you.

Comment: I guess we also can't use FTOC to say that $\ f'(a)=0\  $ for $\ a\ $ in $\ (0,1)\ \implies f(a) =\ $ constant on $\ (0,1)\ $ because FTOC uses MVT... If we could, we could just use IVT at the points $0$ and $1$ to prove whatever was wanting to be proved probably.

Comment: In my opinion the text of question (f) should actually be "**$f'(a) = 0$ for all $a$ in $ [0,1]$**". Without completeness (that is without MVT) there would be no way to state that the right derivative in $0$ is $0$ as a consequence of the fact that the derivative in $(0,1)$ is $0$. If you work in $\Bbb Q$ you could easily construct a (uniformly) continuous function with zero derivative everywhere but in $0$, where the derivative is (e.g.) equal to $1$.

Comment: @dfnu that's sort of the conclusion I have come to, as well. I wrote an answer that gets us to the point of $f'(0)^+=0$, but in the pursuit of that conclusion, there is an obviously different path one can take to answer the question of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a way of proving that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=0$, but the argument used to prove this statement, in and of itself, would defeat the purpose of even pursuing the statement.

WLG, suppose by contradiction that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=L \gt 0$.

Consider when $\varepsilon_0 = \frac{L}{2}$. Then, for any $x \in (0, \delta_{\varepsilon_0})$, we have $\frac{L}{2} \lt \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \lt \frac{3L}{2}$. Rearranging, we have that $f(0) + \frac{L}{2}x \lt f(x) \lt f(0)+\frac{3L}{2}x \quad (\dagger_1)$.

Referencing the hyperlink (with a slight modification), we will make use of the two functions $g_{\varepsilon}$ and $h_{\varepsilon}$, for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$. For $g_{\varepsilon}$, which has the rule $g_{\varepsilon}(x)=f(x)+\varepsilon (x-a)$, look at the interval $[a,b]$ for any $a \lt b \in (0,1)$. Then $g_{\varepsilon}'(x)=f'(x)+\varepsilon \gt 0$. Therefore, on the interval $[a,b]$, $g_{\varepsilon}$ is strictly increasing. As such, $g(a) \lt g(b)$.

This implies that $f(a)\lt f(b)+ (b-a)\varepsilon$. With some algebra, we have that $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} \gt -\varepsilon$. Using $h_{\varepsilon}=(x-a)\varepsilon-f(x)$, we can similarly derive that: $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} \lt \varepsilon$.

Together, we then have that, for any $\varepsilon \gt 0: \left|\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} \right| \lt \varepsilon$, which means $f(a)=f(b)$. $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, so we can generalize. For any $a,b \in (0,1)$, we have that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Now, consider an arbitrary $x \in (0, \delta_{\varepsilon_0})$. Additionally, consider an $x'=\frac{x}{4}$.

By $(\dagger_1)$ we have that:

$$f(0) + \frac{L}{2}x' \lt f(x') \lt f(0)+\frac{3L}{2}x'$$.

However, note that $\frac{3L}{2}x'=\frac{3L}{8}x \lt \frac{L}{2}x$. Combining these facts, we have:

$$f(x') \lt f(0) + \frac{L}{2}x \lt f(x)$$
As such, there is no way that $f(x')$ can equal $f(x)$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $f'(0)^+ \neq L \gt 0$. A similar argument works when assuming $f'(0)^+ \lt L$. As such, $f'(0)^+=0$.

---

Given the purpose of this problem, which is to show that $f(0)=f(1)$, the above approach is excessive. Really, once we have shown that for any $(a,b) \in (0,1): f(a)=f(b)$, the assumption of continuity **alone** at $x=0$ and $x=1$ suffices to show that $f(0)=f(1)$.